# Sorting Hash of Hashes by value

Tags: arrays, perl, hash-of-hashes

I have the following data structure

```
my %HoH = {
      'foo1' => {
                        'bam' => 1,
                        'zip' => 0,
                      },
      'foo2' => {
                         'bam' => 0,
                         'zip' => 1,
                         'boo' => 1
                       }
    };
```

I would like to sort KEY1 (foo1 or foo2) by the VALUE stored in 'zip' in order from greatest to least.

Here's how I'm doing it.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @sorted;
foreach my $KEY1 (keys %HoH) {
    # sort KEY1 by the value 'zip' maps to in descending order
    @sorted = sort {$HoH{$KEY1}{'zip'}{$b} <=> 
        $HoH{$KEY1}{'zip'}{$a}} keys %HoH;
}

print Dumper(\@sorted);
```

I'm getting an weird warning: Reference found where even-sized list expected at test.pl line 6.
Also `print Dumper(\@sorted);` is printing

```
$VAR1 = [
      'HASH(0x1b542a8)'
    ];
```

When it should be printing

```
$VAR1 = [
      ['foo2', 'foo1']
    ];
```

Since `foo2` has 1 `zip` and `foo1` has 0 `zip`.

Comment: A key point of terminology:  You cannot sort a hash.  Hashes have no order.  What you can do is print out things that are in a hash in a given order, but the hash itself is not sorted.  This is different from PHP arrays where they act like hashes but also have sort orders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `%HoH` is declared as a hash, but is defined as a hashreference. Use parentheses `(...)` instead of braces `{...}`.
- You don't need to loop through the hash to sort it. Sort will take care of that.
- if you `sort {...} keys %HoH`, then the special variables `$a` and `$b` represent the keys of `%HoH` as it performs the sort.
- `$a` and `$b` are in reverse order because your expected result is in decreasing order. (Update: Oh I just noticed that you had that in the first place.)
- The `zip` value in the nested hash is `$HoH{$KEY}{'zip'}`, which is what you should sort by.

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Data::Dumper;

  my %HoH = (
        'foo1' => {
                          'bam' => 1,
                          'zip' => 0,
                        },
        'foo2' => {
                           'bam' => 0,
                           'zip' => 1,
                           'boo' => 1
                         }
      );

  my @sorted = sort {$HoH{$b}{'zip'} <=> $HoH{$a}{'zip'}} keys %HoH;
  print Dumper \@sorted;
  ```

Note that the result of this code will give you an array:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'foo2',
      'foo1'
];
```

... not a nested array:

```
$VAR1 = [
     ['foo2', 'foo1']
];
```